# Excel: how do I add one column from start to end with another one from end to start in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have two columns A and B, each have 10 elements, I want to get a column A1+B10, A2+B9, etc.

When I fill `=A1+B10` and do the 'double click' to auto fill the rest, it cannot give me the right answer.

To be clear, I don't want modify column A or column B, and I don't want to sort A and B either, just keep them intact and get column C by just fill one cell and double click to auto fill the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and `ROW` with some calculations:
`= A1 + INDEX(B$1:B$10;10-ROW(C1)+1)`

Comment: +1 Good thinking

Answer (score 9):

You can also use INDIRECT.

```
= A1+INDIRECT("B" & 11-ROW())
```

Answer (score 3):

With Excel 365 you can use `SEQUENCE()` and `SORTBY()`. Enter this formula into cell `C2`:

`=A1:A10+SORTBY(B1:B10,SEQUENCE(10,,10,-1))`